# Are Riak Data Type Set Sorted keys reliable

Tags: database, data-structures, distributed, riak, key-value-store

The binary data stored in CRDT: set seems to be sorted when fetched. Is the set a sorted set? This doesn't seem to be documented as such.

A related question would be how does the Riak 2i performance compare to DyanmoDB range key.

Comment: Upon testing, I didn't find that binary data returned as sorted. Could you add your query and results here (out of curiosity)?

Comment: It'd also be better to break out your DynamoDB question into a separate one with particular aspects of performance measurement (query, data set size, other details that would shift results).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question: the sorting of the keys is an implementation detail: you can't depend on it going forward.